# Spivak's treatement of Conic Sections

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In his book *Calculus*, Spivak goes on to treat conic sections as follows ::

---

One of the simplest subsets of this three-dimensional space is the (infinite) *cone* illustrated in Figure 2; this cone may be produced by rotating a "generaling line," of slope $C$ say, around the third axis.

$\quad$ [image]

For any given first two coordinates $x$ and $y$, the point $(x,y,0)$ in the horizontal plane has distance $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ from the origin, and thus $$\tag1 (x,y,z)\text{ is in the cone if and only if }z=\pm C\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$ We can descend from these three-dimensional vistas to the more familiar two-dimnensional one by asking what happens when we intersect this cone with some plane $P$ (Figure 3).

$\quad$ [image]

If the plane is parallel to the horizontal plane, there's certainly no mystery--the intersection is just a circle. Otherwise, the plane $P$ intersects the horizontal plane in a straight line. We can make things a lot simpler for ourselves if we rotate everything so that this intersection line points straight out from the plane of the paper, while the first axis is in the usual position that we are familiar with. The plane $P$ is thus viewed "straight on," so that all we see (Figure 4) is its intersection $L$ with  the plane of the first and third axes; from this view-point the cone itself simply appears as two straight lines.

$\quad$ [image]

In the plane of the first and third axes, the line $L$ can be described as the collection of all points of the form $$(x,Mx+B),$$ where $M$ is the slope of $L$. For an arbitrary point $(x,y,z)$ it follows that $$\tag2 (x,y,z)\text{ is in the plane }P\text{ if and only if }z=Mx+B.$$ Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we see that $(x,y,z)$ is in the intersection of the cone and the plane if and only if $$\tag{$*$} Mx+B=\pm C\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$ Now we have to choose coordinate axes in the plane $P$. We can choose $L$ as the first axis, measuring distances from the intersection $Q$ with the horizontal plane (Figure 5); for the second axis we just choose the line through $Q$ parallel to our original second axis. If the first coordinate of a point in $P$ with respect to these axis is $x$, then the first coordinate of this point with respect to the original axes can be written in the form $$\alpha x+\beta$$ for some $\alpha$ and $\beta$. On the other hand, if the second coordinate of the point with respect to these axes is $y$, then $y$ is also the second coordinate with respect to the original axes.

$\quad$ [image]

Consequently, $(*)$ says that the point lies on the intersection of the plane and the cone if and only if $$M(\alpha x+\beta)+B=\pm C\sqrt{(\alpha x+\beta)^2+y^2}.$$ Although this looks fairly complicated, after squaring we can write this as $$\alpha^2C^2y^2+\alpha^2(M^2-A^2)x^2+Ex+F=0$$ for some $E$ and $F$ that we won't bother writing out. Dividing by $\alpha^2$ simplifies this to $$C^2y^2+(C^2-M^2)x^2+Gx+H=0.$$

---

## My Question:

> Why did he have to add the $\alpha x+\beta$ step? Why did he choose these particular coordinates? Is that so that he can translate the coordinates on the plane to those of the $xyz$ coordinate system? Any clarifications are welcome!

Comment: I have the same question. Have you figured out the answer yet? The answer by @justin-benfield has not helped me.

Comment: @user245312 Sorry for being late, I'll try to get back here and see.

Answer (score 2):

The transformation $\alpha x +\beta$ transforms your $x$-coordinates originally in the $x$-$z$ plane to the corresponding coordinates in the plane $P$ which intersects the $x$-$z$ plane as the line $L$.

Answer (score 0):

We're looking for the equation that gives us the set of points where the plane intersects the cone. If we didn't introduce $\alpha x + \beta$, we merely get the projection of the intersecting points onto the x-y plane, which would be the same shape but with distorted proportions. If we wanted to see how the intersection would look **on the plane P**, we have to change the input for $x$ so that a single unit change in the original $x$-axis corresponds to the same change on the "planar" axis, thus giving us an ellipse/hyperbola/circle with the correct dimensions.